# CSRF Exempt Django Auth Password Reset View for Cross Domain request

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-csrf

I have a separate front end and backend site and I am trying to enable users on the front end to reset their password.  I have created an endpoint for them to do so which works when accessed via the backend site.  But when I try to access the endpoint via Insomnia I get:

> Forbidden (403)
>
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

I have added my front end domain to the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`.

```
class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'users/reset_password.html'

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there some other method that I must also make `csrf_exempt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView` decorates its `dispatch` method with `csrf_protect`, where `csrf_protect = decorator_from_middleware(CsrfViewMiddleware)`.

Wrapping with your `csrf_exempt` and the actual `CsrfViewMiddleware`, we have `csrf_protect(csrf_exempt(csrf_protect(<bound method PasswordResetView.dispatch ...>)))`, where `<bound method PasswordResetView.dispatch ...>` is `super().dispatch`.

That can be reduced to `csrf_protect(<bound method PasswordResetView.dispatch ...>)`.

We can trick `CsrfViewMiddleware` by setting `request.csrf_processing_done = True`:

```py
class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'users/reset_password.html'

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.csrf_processing_done = True
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you can set `super().dispatch.__wrapped__.csrf_exempt = True` but this has the side effect of also affecting other view classes that inherit `auth_views.PasswordResetView`, since `super().dispatch.__wrapped__` is just `<function PasswordResetView.dispatch ...>`.